# How to remove chapter indentation in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

First post so please be gentle :)

I'm relatively new to Latex but have managed to bumble my way through using package manuals and stack exchange. But now I'm stuck on something I'm not sure how to solve...
I've added in a code section that removes 'chapter' from the headings and contents, but not the contents seem to have this weird indent.  How do I get rid of this indent?

Here is a picture:

[image: ToC problem]

The preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
% Include any additional packages
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, top=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, center]{caption}                                             % Changes font size of figure captions to small
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-comp,
    natbib=true,
    maxnames=2,
    sorting=nyt,
    sortcites=false,
    block=space,
    date=long,
    url=false, 
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    isbn=false,
    uniquename=false,
    uniquelist=false,
    terseinits=true,
    firstinits=false
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../../BibTex/library.bib}
%Put initials after names...
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}    
%Remove "and" before last name. However, this also removes "and" in a textcite...
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sidecap}                                
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage[big,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle=Report,
        pdfauthor=EL,
        pdfkeywords=Thesis
        }
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} % Automates the generation of an acronyms list
\makeindex
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}% Set document line spacing to 1.5
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: If you have a picture, then use the "image" button to upload and include it, but remove the `!` in front of what the system types. A user with enough privileges will be able to reinstate the image.

Comment: lockstep: Sorry for the Thank You

egreg: I've inserted the pic and removed the ! as per your instructions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want unnumbered chapters, just say

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

instead of clearing `\chaptername` and `\thechapter`.

---

By the way, setting `\baselinestretch` and `\parindent` is better done with the `setspace` and `parskip` packages. Of course my advice is to use neither increased baseline skip nor zero indentation: both hinder legibility.

Comment: The main reason I went with \parindent was due to the bibliography.  We have to use this author-year style and if you use parskip, all the bibliography entries have no indent reducing readability.  If I could keep the indent, or have some sort of bulletpoint/character denoting the start of each reference, then I might go with parskip.    

Is this possible?  Has it been solved already?  And do I need to create another question for it?

Comment: @E_L This is a completely different question.